# Sum time between dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I have a MySQL table looking like this. It's basically a time sheet for tasks.

```
  id  |  task  |  user  |          start        |         stop          |  running
------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------
  1   |   12   |   2    |  2009-10-01 10:05:00  |  2009-10-01 14:23:00  |  0
  1   |   13   |   4    |  2009-10-05 08:58:00  |  2009-10-05 12:16:00  |  0
  1   |   14   |   3    |  2009-10-05 20:30:00  |  2009-10-05 22:00:00  |  0
```

I want to sum the time spent:

1) Today
2) Yesterday
3) This week
4) Last week
5) This month
6) Last month

I don't need the queries for each of theese, but just the first one to get me started. I'm not that familiar with different date functions in MySQL, and I think it's difficult to read and navigate through their documentation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not [THAT difficult](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to navigate through MySQL documentation.

You need [TIMEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and [`TIME_TO_SEC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) functions.

```
select SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop, start))) from my_table
  where start >= CURRENT_DATE() and stop <= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

will get you total time (in seconds) spent on tasks today. Look at [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) if you're going to specify criteria for other ranges (e.g. last month, etc) in MySQL instead of supplying them as parameters to your query.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "+ INVERVAL 1 DAY" in where. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'TODAY' Date, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(stop - start))) TimeSpent
FROM table1
WHERE start >= CURDATE()
  AND stop < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```